# Perform delete a perticular records after some interval of time in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mysql-event

```
DROP EVENT `deleteTestEntries`;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` EVENT `deleteTestEntries`
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
    STARTS '2018-05-25 18:17:01'
    ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO
    DELETE FROM lead_master WHERE lead_master.lname LIKE '%Test%'
```

What is wrong in above event.
It has been created with no errors but not performing any action.
I simply want to delete the records from my lead_master table where lname is 'Test'

Comment: This is probably the wrong way to solve your problem.  I would suggest that you ask another question with more details about your table and what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it with cron jobs.
I created a controller which calls a model function contains query to delete record.
and set the cron job which calls the controller after specific interval of time.

Answer (score 1):

Go into my.ini file and add this line,most probably this is the issue.

```
event_scheduler = on
```

Restart mysql.Apparently you can even [set it on the fly](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you don't need an event every minute.  Just define a view to filter out the records you don't want:

```
create view v_lead_master as
    select lm.*
    from lead_master lm
    where lm.lname not like '%Test%';
```

Then schedule a job or event every day at a slow period to delete the rows you want.  Your application should use the view.  Your testing should use the base table.

Comment: this approach will keep on storing useless data in db. which will increase the size of db...